# Validate Using Enum in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, validation, enums

i have a problem with validate my query in mysql using enum. as i know mysql doesnt support with constraint so i use enum

Example code :

```
alter table jewerly modify gender enum('M','F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M';
```

it run well if i use like above, but i have a problem to validate in another condition.

i want to modify validation with enum for : inputted productID format must like : PR[xxx], xxx means the number. if we use constraint, it will be like 'PR[0-9][0-9][0-9]', 
but i dont know how to use in enum.

```
alter table jewelry modify jewelid enum('PR[0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL;
```

i tried this query above but it doesnt work.. any idea?

Comment: From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html):
An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal. 

You may be out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: That's not the way enums work in MySQL. See the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html); you cannot use regex in enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do makes no sense in MySQL.  You seem to be using a regular expression format for an `enum` definition.

Although enum can be used for such validation, it has some drawbacks.  There are limits to the number of values, for instance.  Changing the type can be problematic -- such as fixing a spelling error.

Instead, you might consider use foreign keys for this purpose:

```
create table ref_jewelid (
    jewelid varchar(255)
);

create table jewelry (
    . . .
    constraint fk_jewelid foreign key (jewelid) references ref_jewelid(jewelid)
);
```

You would then populate `ref_jewelid` with the valid values, perhaps using a spreadsheet to generate the names.  You might even take this one step further and have `jewelid` be a *bona fide* numeric id, with the name being one attribute of it.  That is the approach I would probably take.